# Using ViewFlipper.onInterceptTouchEvent in practice

Tags: android

I'm having [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650863/setontouchlistener-not-called-on-viewflipper). I want to capture the touch events fired by any of the children of a particular ViewFlipper. According to that question, what I should do is extend the ViewFlipper class and override the onInterceptTouchEvent method. But I'm struggling with how to actually do that in practice. Currently, my ViewFlipper is hard-coded right into the XML for my layout. How can I put an instance of my subclass into the XML? Will I be forced to insert it into the layout programmatically?

Also, ordinarily to use touch events I would attach a listener to the View object. Even if I have a subclass of ViewFlipper where I override onInterceptTouchEvent, how do I dispatch the touch event to the listeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just reference the class name directly in the XML

instead of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <ViewFilpper />
</LinearLayout>
```

you would use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <com.example.customviews.MyViewFilpper />
</LinearLayout>
```

obviously that's missing attributes but I think you get it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you have to include the whole package structure. Any ideas for the second paragraph of my question?

Comment: just create a new listener interface that you can set on your custom ViewFlipper then call that interface from your onInterceptTouchEvent override.